# '/' character in routing parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was using a routing pattern. Recently, I've changed the pattern. Now, I'm struggling with an issue that annoys me.

I'd like to catch the following URL:

http://www.mysite.com/news_title/-1322.html

routing pattern:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "haber2",
                    url: "{noFollow}-{id}.html",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Anasayfa", action = "HaberID" },
                    constraints: new {id = "\\d+"}
                );
```

While clicking the link below, I'm facing with not found. How to overcome this problem?

Any helps, tricks is very appreciated.

Comment: This might be help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463330/enforce-hyphens-in-net-mvc-4-0-url-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Not possible.

Slash in route will definitely create this problem. 
Default Routing engine always searches routing pattern based on no. of slashes in URL.

I tried it with wild card character '*' like catch all routes.

something like following.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "haber2",
                    url: "{noFollow*}-{id}.html",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Anasayfa", action = "HaberID" },
                    constraints: new {id = "\\d+"}
                );
```

but without luck..

Hope helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a slash in your url:

```
 routes.MapRoute(name: "haber2",
                url: "{noFollow}/-{id}.html",
                defaults: new { controller = "Anasayfa", action = "HaberID" },
                constraints: new {id = "\\d+"}
            );
```

Comment: Please mind that 'news_title/' come from database. Also 'news_title' may come from database. So routing pattern cannot be changed.

Comment: Ok, then why don't you simply map another route to satisfy the other case?

Comment: yes this is a solution and I did by rewrite engine. But this is not the right answer for my question, thanks.